# How do I let Google know of a problem so they can fix it?

Tags: gmail, google

My husband signed in to his gmail account on my laptop and when we tried to sign him out through his icon photo the drop screen wouldn't pop down to allow us to hit the sign out button. How do I let Google know of this problem so they can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

- Use [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/)

## Explanation

Google Feedback is the tool that Google includes on many of their web applications to make easier for users send feedback directly to the engineers in charge of the corresponding web application.

[image: Google Feedback]

<sup>*Picture taken from Google Feedback*</sup>

On some applications, like old Gmail, click on the cog button, then on Send Feedback, just as it's shown on the above picture.